# If x,y inside coordinate box

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

i have been trying to find an efficient solution to this:

```
def hit(pos,box):
    if pos[0] > box[0]:
        if pos[0] < box[0]+box[2]:
            if pos[1] > box[1]:
                if pos[1] < box[1]+box[3]:
                    return True
    return False
pos = (50,132); box = (20,50,60,150)
hit(pos,box)
```

I am using pygame and want to calculate if the x,y coordinates are inside the x,y,x+,y+ box. Pixel perfection is not an issue. I have tried putting all the if checks inside a big and-and-and operation but it seems to have the same speed.

Comment: Just check at once if your x coordinate is between the minX and maxX, and if your y coordinate is between the minY and maxY. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is efficient, however you could make it more elegant and concise like so:

```
def hit(pos,box):
    return box[0]+box[2] > pos[0] > box[0] and box[1]+box[3] > pos[1] > box[1]
```

Since we're returning `boolean` values we can just join our conditions together.

Comment: I tested my own method against this one and yours is faster! I thought that instantly returning False upon receiving a non-match would be faster than turning more calculations into a single boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your codes *intent* far clearer:

```
def isInside(pos,box):
    p_x, p_y = pos

    min_x = box[0]
    max_x = min_x + box[2]
    min_y = box[1]
    max_y = min_y + box[3]

    return min_x <= p_x <= max_x and min_y <= p_y <= max_y
```

This is 5(7) lines more then strictly needed - but if you wake up at 2am and get this code to interprete what it does ... you can *see* what it does.

The one-liner is in [Filip Młynarski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417667/7505395) answer.

Comment: Yeah i didn't include it in the question but i sometimes add comments next to my functions. mine had: # Determine if pos[x,y] is inside box[x,y,x+,y+]

Comment: @Walter thats my point. You need a comment to explain what you do. This code is self-explanatory. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pygame, then `box` should be a [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html), and then you could use [`collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint):

```
pos = (50,132)
box = pygame.Rect((20,50,60,150))

hit = box.collidepoint(pos)
```